# How to determine the trend of a RSSI list in Python

Tags: python, algorithm, math, rssi, trend

Is there any way to find out what's the trend of the list of RSSI?

For example:

`[-60,5, -59,45, -54,91, -54,07, -49,93]`. RSSI value increasing over time.

`[-61,95, -61, -63,6, -65,11, -68,5]`. RSSI value decreasing over time.

I am looking at the last 5 values to find the trend of RSSI values. By looking at these last 5 values, I would like to find out if the RSSI value has increased or decreased. In addition, the increase and decrease values are important to me.